# 'Metadata file could not be found' error when referencing assembly in T4

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, t4

I have class library `A` and library `B` with T4 template.
B references A, and assembly directive exist inside template:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)A.dll" #>
```

When I run template transformation error is shown:

> Compiling transformations: Metadatafile: 'path\A.dll' could not be
>   found.

But this file is there!

I get this error in VS 2012.

Have no idea what causes this error.

**Update**

Well, I found a mistake in assembly directive, just mistyped.

Comment: One of these variables $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir) are empty. path/ is maybe projectdir?

Comment: @KayNelson, the path is correct, if I open it with explorer I can see the file.

Comment: And is the file A.dll in working folder of path? Try putting the file on C:\A.dll and see if it work if you change the code to that. SOunds to me like your solution folder oesnt have the A.dll file

Comment: @KeyNelson, shame on me, one subtle symbol, I just mistyped, the real names are not A and B.