# t4 template - Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework isn't defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4

I need to use database context in t4 template so first I have to create databasecontext in t4 template:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<#@ assembly name="$(TargetPath)" #>
<#@ import namespace="MyProject.DAL" #>

<#
    DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext();
#>
```

But I have error that type Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework isn't defined - why??

This is my DatabaseContext class which I want to use:

```
namespace MyProject.DAL
{
    public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DatabaseContext() : base("DatabaseContext") { }
    }
}
```

I have added to file tt:

```
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" #>
```

But now I have error:

> cannot find metadata file Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

Comment: Just a guess here, but I suspect you need to add an assembly `<#@ assembly name="WhateverEntityFrameworkUses" #>` and an import `<#@ import namespace="EF's Namespace" #>`.  You MAY also need to set `hostspecific` to true... maybe...

Comment: I have edded that but now I have error: cannot find metadata file Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

Comment: Is the assembly name correct?  See this question as a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20522037/1467396. I'm wondering if you need to do something like <#@ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll" #>  Also, don't get too hung up on this idea about assemblies and imports--it's just a guess :)